# Spring boot endpoints with JsonView for multiple clients

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm creating endpoints with Spring Boot and I have many clients that will consume them. I would like to some fields of response when some client make a request and show them for others. I'm a using JsonView from Jackson package, I readed that documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-methods/jackson.html It works fine. But my use case is a bit different. An endpoint can be called by many clients. I know the requester by meta data in request header. Each client has its class view.

I would like each time a client make a request, JsonView consider its view class and ignore others and so on. But I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If the client can be distinguished through the header, JsonView can be used like below.

Controller

```java
package com.example.so77224709;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public MappingJacksonValue getUser(@RequestHeader("Client-Meta-Data") String data) {
        User user = new User();

        MappingJacksonValue result = new MappingJacksonValue(user);
        Class<?> viewClazz;
        switch (data) {
            case "A" :
                viewClazz = User.ClientAView.class;
                break;
            case "B" :
                viewClazz = User.ClientBView.class;
                break;
            case "C" :
                viewClazz = User.ClientCView.class;
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Meta data not defined.");
        }
        result.setSerializationView(viewClazz);
        return result;
    }


    public static class User {
        public interface ClientAView {};
        public interface ClientBView {};
        public interface ClientCView {};

        @JsonView(ClientAView.class)
        public String a = "a";

        @JsonView(ClientBView.class)
        public String b = "b";

        @JsonView(ClientCView.class)
        public String c = "c";
    }
}
```

Request

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8080/user' \
--header 'Client-Meta-Data: B'
```

Response

```json
{
    "b": "b"
}
```

This code is example code.
I would implement a resolver that resolve client specific view through the header and replace the switch statement.

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion. Is there a way to make it work for all requests without adding those statements in each method?

Comment: Sorry for late. Customizing MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter or adding ResponseBodyAdvice will hekp implement behavior in various requests.